# What is the difference between Stack 100h and Org 100h?

Tags: assembly, tasm

I'm trying to review assembly language and I noticed that there is a stack 100h. Can someone help me and explain this? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`stack 100h` reserves 100h bytes for stack. `org 100h` sets the current address to 100h, that is the address the assembler is assuming.

Note that `stack 100h` applies to `exe` files, it's going to be written in a header so the loader provides that much stack for you. `org 100h` typically applies to `com` files, because those are loaded at address `100h`.

Comment: Thanks Jester!! Now I understand both terms

Comment: @Gotch if you are still around please "accept" this answer. That's the spirit!